# Original Series Trek episode where the crew go to a planet where whatever they think comes true

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

Does anyone know the name of the episode from the original *Star Trek* series where they are on a planet and whatever they think becomes true?

I remember Bones McCoy was thinking about a beautiful "damsel" and she appears from behind a rock, and then a knight in armor lances him through the chest and he

> dies but is taken to a place under the planet surface where they make these things appear on the surface (and therefore can revive Dr. McCoy)?

Comment: This it? - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Shore_Leave_(episode)

Comment: Bones initially thinks about Alice in Wonderland, which causes a white rabbit to run by, followed by Alice. He later converses with yeoman Barrows where they exchange one or two lines on the topic of knights and damsels in distress, whereupon a white gown appears, which she changes into behind some bushes for privacy. No damsel "appears", it is the yeoman after her temporary costume change. But yes, he gets impaled by an armored knight on horseback and subsequently disappears to be healed and later reappear none the worse for wear.

Answer (score 24):

This is almost certainly [TOS: Shore Leave](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Shore_Leave_(episode))

> **Kirk:**... things of fantasy, which are undeniably real, begin to appear...

You can see the knight and the damsel just before the end of the trailer.

Comment: "almost" certainly? There are a few subtle discrepancies in the O/P's recollection of the events, but this *is* the episode in question.

Comment: @AnthonyX - When they accept it (assuming they do), I'll edit it to reflect that.

Comment: I already know this is the one.

Comment: this is the episode.